# Self join table on previous month data to add missing records

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I am trying to join Impala table with previous month data to check missing records in current month. I have Employee records in source table.  If an employee is not present in current month but was there in previous month, then need to label this employee as "Terminated"

Tried to do the left outer join with date condition and employee name but it is not returning the missing record.

Employee current month equals employee previous month

Current reporting month equals previous reporting month

```
Input Data:

+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+
|employee | branch  | hire_date | reporting_month|
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+
| James   | EE      | 20170101  |   20190131     |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+
| Judy    | GIP     | 20181014  |   20190131     |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+
| James   | EE      | 20170101  |   20190228     |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+
| Judy    | GIP     | 20181014  |   20190228     |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+
| James   | EE      | 20170101  |   20190331     |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+
| Judy    | GIP     | 20181014  |   20190331     |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+
| James   | EE      | 20170101  |   20190430     |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+
| Max     | EEI     | 20170201  |   20190430     |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+
```

Suppose current reporting month is 20190430 and employee Judy is not present then record needs to be added for Judy with  term flag as "Terminated"

```
Expected Output:

+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
|employee | branch  | hire_date | reporting_month| Term_flag |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| James   | EE      | 20170101  |   20190131     | NULL      |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| Judy    | GIP     | 20181014  |   20190131     | NULL      |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| James   | EE      | 20170101  |   20190228     | NULL      |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| Judy    | GIP     | 20181014  |   20190228     | NULL      |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| James   | EE      | 20170101  |   20190331     | NULL      |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| Judy    | GIP     | 20181014  |   20190331     | NULL      |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| James   | EE      | 20170101  |   20190430     | NULL      |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| Judy    | GIP     | 20181014  |   20190430     |Terminated | 
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| Max     | EEI     | 20170201  |   20190430     | NULL      |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
```

Comment: For the `reporting_month` values in the expected output, and using the input data you provided, all of the `Term_flag` values should be `Terminated`.  If that is not what you expect, please provide more complete sample data.

Comment: The statements like `Employee current month equals employee previous month` are unclear.  That can't be what you really mean.  Please clarify.

Comment: @dougp - I am trying to report data for each month - for example employee "Judy" is available in reporting month 20190131, 20190228, 20190331 but not in 20190430. This means Judy was terminated in month of April 2019. In source table we don't have an entry for Judy in April but we need to have an entry in Output with term_flag value as "Terminated".
As Judy was there in all other prior months - value for term_flag will be NULL

I hope I am able to clear the expected output

Comment: Sorry.  Ignore my first comment.  It looks like I was blinded by the mesmerizing presentation style of StackOverflow tables.  I wish they would allow something that looks better.

Comment: @dgoup - I have added one more employee in April 2019 month which is expected as it in in April reporting month with term_flag as NULL

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the magic date for `20190430` comes from.  The basic idea is `union all` as follows:

```
select employee, branch, hire_date, reporting_month, null as term_flag
from input
union all
select employee, branch, hire_date, 20190430 as reporting_month, 'terminated'
from (select i.*,
             row_number() over (order by reporting_month desc) as seqnum
      from input i
     ) i
where seqnum = 1 and
      months_add(trunc(reporting_month, 'MON') , 1) < '2019-04-01';
```

The month arithmetic may be a little tricky, because your date is the last day of the month rather than the first.